# Vue-loader Syntax Error: Unexpected token { when importing a component from a js file

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-loader

I have a vue 2 project that was using webpack 2.  I had abandoned it for a while and then returned to find several errors I thought might be related to old versions, so I upgraded to webpack 3, and updated vue-loader.

Now I seem to get an error `Syntax Error: Unexpected token {` every time I try to import a component into a js file.

For example:

```
import App from './App.vue'
```

from the main.js file gives me the error.  Importing a component from within another vue component doesn't seem to give me any problems.

Also here is how I'm initializing the app in main.js. All of this worked previously.

`new Vue({
  router: router,
  store,
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})`

I'm not sure if this is an issue with vue-loader or webpack configuration or a combination of both.

Here are my versions from package.json:

    `"vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-resource": "^1.3.4",
    "vue-router": "^2.8.1",
    "vuex": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.20.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^2.6.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^3.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.2.11",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",`

Comment: Can you post the complete files?

Comment: sure, here is the main.js entry point: https://gist.github.com/tyler-g/24023a5e8ac9e0e02a685c267ae62680   and here is the main Vue file: https://gist.github.com/tyler-g/3de300678f3002da369abbfe6d415370

Comment: And the package.json? that last trailing comma in `"babel-register": "^6.22.0",` is a syntax error in `.json` files.

Comment: ah, yes that was just a snippet.  Here is the full package.json: https://gist.github.com/tyler-g/02df570b3738075dea1dd31c6ff47ec1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try upgrading npm to latest version.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  I can't say if it was node or npm in particular, but upgrading to node 7 fixed the issue

Comment: I wasted so much time on that. @tyler-g, I think this should be accepted answer.